# how to use Windows Explorer to search contents of extensionless files

Tags: windows-7, windows

I wanted to find a 'makefile' that contained a target name.
But Windows Explorer > File Contents doesn't search files in each makefile.
I assume this is because there is no extension to filename 'makefile'.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Answer (score 0):

This is *not an answer within Windows built-in Search, but an alternative*. If you want a GUI, [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) and similar search software (see [Alternative to Agent Ransack](http://alternativeto.net/software/agent-ransack/) provide capabilities not in Windows Search.